# How to limit axis in matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to plot a piece of pie using a `matplotlib` polar plot like so:

```
Fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
ax.bar(math.pi/3.0, 5.0, width=math.pi/3.0)
ax.bar(math.pi/3.0, 3.0, width=math.pi/3.0)

# Adjust the axis
ax.set_ylim(math.pi/3.0, 2*math.pi/3.0)
```

I only want to see the part of the graph between `math.pi/3.0` and `2*math.pi/3.0`. Is this even possible?

Comment: what do you see when you do this? what happens?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand what you are looking for, but if you want to see only the piece of pie, you can do that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

Fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))
ax.bar(math.pi/3.0, 5.0, width=math.pi/3.0)
ax.bar(math.pi/3.0, 3.0, width=math.pi/3.0)

# Adjust the axis
ax.set_ylim(math.pi/3.0, 2*math.pi/3.0)

ax.set_frame_on(False)
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I want. The only thing that could make it better would be to have the tick labels still visible so I know the scale I'm working with. Is that possible? Can I place those tick marks right along the edge of the piece of pie?